# How to handle missing Swing plaf.windows classes in Java 11?

Tags: java, swing, api, internals

I'm migrating a multiplatform (Windows and Linux) desktop application from java8 to OpenJDK 11.
The code extends a Swing class and for that we define a new class that extends the `WindowsTabbedPaneUI` internal API class. This class is used when the application runs on Windows.

The code does the following:

```
   ...
   if (this.getUI() instanceof WindowsTabbedPaneUI) {
       this.setUI(new CustomWindowsTabbedPaneUI());
   }
   ...
```

where `CustomWindowsTabbedPaneUI` extends `WindowsTabbedPaneUI`.

This was working fine with java 8. However, now when I run on java 11 jre it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsTabbedPaneUI
```

I tried using the --add-opens and --add-exports options when launching the application but I could not make it work.
I understand the reason is that the linux jre for java 11 does not include that class.
I believe that's the case since running the command below does not list the `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows` package:

```
java --describe-module java.desktop
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe [Swing Issue on Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51555030/85421)

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I read that post. However, that indicates how to address the problem at compile time, which just pushes the problem at runtime (see https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/). What I need now is a solution at run time.

Comment: If your app is multi-platform **and** contains Windows specific code, it must also contain linux specific code, no? So you would have the same issue with linux specific classes that are removed from the JDK.

Comment: It was using the base look & feel for linux, by extending from BasicTabbedPaneUI. But you are right, since I plan to use the Metal look and feel now.

Comment: Simply check for the base non-internal class `BasicTabbedPaneUI` instead. Maybe with a check on Windows if so desired.

Comment: Thanks to all. I ended up extending BasicTabbedPaneUI.