# OpenJDK 11: Getting ClassNotFound on Linux, works fine on windows

Tags: java, swing, java-11, classnotfoundexception

We have a desktop-based swing app running fine with Oracle JDK 1.8. After moving to OpenJDK 11 we got some not found exceptions for classes `com.sun.java.swing.Painter`, we resolved that by generating a bundled jar that contains some classes of `com.sun.java.swing.Painter.java` and some 4-5 classes and added it by

```
java --patch-module java.desktop=custombundle.jar -classpath path_of_jars starter_class*
```

Now everything works fine with AdoptOpenJDK11 or OpenJDK11 on Windows systems. But on Linux (Ubuntu-64 bits or any ARM-based Linux environments) we got another class not found/No class def exception related to class `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` from the third-party libraries we used.

We can not remove the calls to `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel` because they are in 3rd party libs. The company providing the libs and also other forum sites suggest adding:

```
--add-exports java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED*
```

```
java --add-exports java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED --patch-module java.desktop=custombundle.jar -classpath path_of_jars starter_class*
```

but after adding this get a warning such as

```
WARNING: package com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows not in java.desktop
```

and we got still the class not found exceptions for `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`

I tried `java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk` instead of `java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows`, the warning disappeared but still not working. Any suggestions?

Adopt OpenJDK version: latest (11.0.8.10)

Ubuntu: 20.04 (recent)

Note: [Swing Issue on Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555030/swing-issue-on-java-10) did not help

Comment: The classes for the WindowsLookAndFeel are only included  in Windows versions of the Jdk.

Comment: yes i saw them with --describe. so the solution must be the third party related upgrade etc. I think

Comment: *"But on linux (ubnutu-64 bits or any ARM based linux environments) we got another class not found/No class def exceptions related to com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel from the third party libraries we used."* Why on Earth would Linux users want to see a Windows styled GUI?!? The safest bet is to use the ***native*** PLAF. Then users on all systems get to see a GUI which closely resembles (and in some case is indistinguishable from) the other apps on their OS.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this ? One of my third-party widget library is also relying on the WindowsLookAndFeel...

Comment: I generated a manual jar containins the classes, I know it is not the best solution and seems weird but worked

Comment: @AndrewThompson my Jenkins runs on linux, and should me able do build Windows apps… This is why on Earth.

Comment: I wondered if there is any way to *try* to import `WindowsLookAndFeel` and to catch the error if this class does not to exist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71584986/wrap-an-import-statement-with-a-try-catch-block