# Wrap an import-statement with a try-catch-block

Tags: java, exception

I would like wrap an *import*-statement with a *try-catch*-block.
How can I do this in Java?

In more detail, I want to import

```
import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;
```

However, this class is only available if the JDK runs on Windows. It is not available when I build the same come on Linux (e. g. in Jenkins, see [OpenJDK 11: class not found error com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990097/openjdk-11-class-not-found-error-com-sun-java-swing-plaf-windows-windowslookand)).

So, I would like to do something like

```
try { 
    import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;
} catch(Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

In Python, it is possilbe to wrap imports with a try-block. Is there a similar solution in Java?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288083/java-conditional-imports help?

Comment: Import statements in java are just an instruction to the compiler so you don't have to type the packages when you are defining and instanciating objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @luk2302 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288083/java-conditional-imports helped.